# Sensor Topic Conventions

Tags: ros, best-practices, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a sensor that will be used in several locations in a robot (e.g. multiple instances of a single hardware device).  Is there a preferred naming convention for message topics under these situations?  I have not been able to find anything under the [ROS Best Practices](http://www.ros.org/wiki/BestPractices) page

It seems like ideally, one would like to remap the root topic while maintaining the subtopics,

```
/sensor/raw
/sensor/calibrated
```

launching as

```
/remapped_sensor/raw
/remapped_sensor/calibrated
```

however the "remap" tag appears to only work for full topics.

Two other options seem to be nesting under a namespace (somewhat reduntantly) e.g.

```
/location_namespace/sensor/raw    
/location_namespace/sensor/calibrated
```

Or alternately, defining a launchfile argument (with default value) that specifies the root topic

```
/launch_arg/raw
/launch_arg/calibrated
```

Or perhaps there are other conventions?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38948/sensor-topic-conventions/) by [ljentoft](https://answers.ros.org/users/657/ljentoft/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What we like to do is have the sensor topics exist (or be remapped to) in what appears to be the global namespace, then nest the node launch under a namespace. That's your /location_namespace/ example, without the redundancy.

For example (code untested, but I think it gives you the idea):

```
<group ns="location"/>
   <node pkg="foo" name="bar" type="baz">
      <remap from="camera/rgb/image_color" to="rgb/image_color"/>
     <remap from="camera/camera_info" to="camera_info"/>
   </node>
</group>
```

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5